# Summing Filtered Transaction Entries

Tags: swiftui

I have an app feature that filters transaction entries (stored in coreData via SwiftData) based on the transaction category. It displays the transactions in a list and I would also like to display the category monetary total.

I have tried calling a func from the filteredCategories ForEach loop in order to display the sum of the filtered categories. But this produces the error "Fixing the Type () cannot conform to View" because the view isn't really display anything.

I next looked into a class method to go through all of the coreData entries checking first for whether the selected entry is the selected category before adding the transaction amount to the summer. But this has its own problems such as is it possible to use SwiftData @Query in a method?

So I'm looking for ideas on how to modify the first option summing transaction entries within a view.

The code below is called when the user has tapped a category contained within a list of all categories.

```
struct FilteredView: View {

    var catFilter: String

    @State private var sortOrder = SortDescriptor(\TravelEntries.entryCatName)
    @EnvironmentObject var currencies: CurrencyModel

    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { g in
            VStack {

                ShowFilteredHeader(g: g)

                filteredCategories(sort: sortOrder, catFilter: catFilter, g: g)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    Text("\(catFilter) Expense Entries")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct filteredCategories: View {
    
    let catFilter: String
    let g: GeometryProxy
    
    @EnvironmentObject var base: BaseModel
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var viewContext

    @Query(sort: \TravelEntries.entryDate, order: .reverse) var travelEntries: [TravelEntries]
    
    @State private var myCatTotal: Double = 0.0 // summer of transaction amounts
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            ForEach(travelEntries) { item in
                
                // sum transaction amounts
                sumTotal(myCatTotal: $myCatTotal, item: item) <-- new code producing error
                
                // display transaction details
                showFilterRow(g: g, item: item)
            }
        }
        .onDelete(perform: deleteItem)
    }
    .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    
    // display category total  <-- show new filtered total here
    let filteredTotal = myCatTotal.formatted(.currency(code: base.baseCur.baseS).precision(.fractionLength(2)))
    Text("Total \(catFilter) Expense: \(filteredTotal)")
       
}

// summer is not working
func sumTotal(myCatTotal: Double, item: TravelEntries)
            $myCatTotal += item.entryMoneyH
}

init(sort: SortDescriptor<TravelEntries>, catFilter: String, g: GeometryProxy) {
    
    self.catFilter = catFilter
    self.g = g
    
    _travelEntries = Query(filter: #Predicate {
        if catFilter.isEmpty {
            return true
            
        } else {
            return $0.entryCatName.localizedStandardContains(catFilter)
        }
    }, sort: [sort])
}


struct showFilterRow: View {

    var g: GeometryProxy
    var item: TravelEntries
    
    @EnvironmentObject var base: BaseModel

    var columns1: [GridItem] = [
        GridItem(.fixed(200)),
        GridItem(.fixed(150))
    ]

    var body: some View {

        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: item))  {

            VStack (alignment: .leading) {

                LazyVGrid (
                    columns: columns1,
                    alignment: .leading
                ) {

                    // entry date: short month spelling
                    Text(formatDate(item: item, mnWide: false))

                    // location
                    Text("\(item.entryLocCity) \(item.entryLocState) \(item.entryLocCountry)")

                    // transaction amount
                    let cCode = item.entryCode
                    let totalValue = item.entryMoneyL
                    let gotTotal = totalValue.formatted(.currency(code: cCode).precision(.fractionLength(2)))
                    Text(gotTotal)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is quite confusing and not easy to understand with both new and old code but usually this is done by creating a computed property that uses `reduce(into:)` on an array of objects to calculate and return the sum of a property